# ¿Como recorrer un json e insertarlo en un array en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

mi json viene asi:

```
 0:
ciu: "ciudad1"
fe: "2018-01-04 12:04:03"
hu: "46"
id: "62577"
__proto__: Object
1:
ciu: "ciudad2"
fe: "2018-01-02 14:35:16"
hu: "737"
id: "63801"
__proto__: Object
2:
ciu: "ciudad2"
fe: "2018-01-02 14:58:45"
hu: "545"
id: "63824"
__proto__: Object
3:
ciu: "ciudad3"
fe: "2018-01-02 15:35:46"
hu: "33"
id: "63853"
```

Lo que quiero hacer es guardar en un array las ciudades ciudad1 en un array, ciudad 2 en otro array y ciudad3 en otro array, despues de ahi comparar si en el array de ciudad1 la fecha es entre 2018-01-01 a 2018-01-31 guardarla en un array, esto es para checar en la ciudad1 en el mes de enero cuantos registros se llenaron y asi hasta llegar a diciembre, asi sucesivamente para las demas ciudades, nadamas que no tengo idea de como hacerlo, algun consejo?

Comment: La respuesta es un json array así que si asignas la respuesta a una variable tendrás un array por defecto.

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar, la pinta que tiene un json como el que me estas hablando es esta:

```
[{
        "ciu": "ciudad1",
        "fe": "2018-01-04 12:04:03",
        "hu": "46",
        "id": "62577"
    },
    {
        "ciu": "ciudad2",
        "fe": "2018-01-02 14:35:16",
        "hu": "737",
        "id": "63801"
    },
    {
        "ciu": "ciudad2",
        "fe": "2018-01-02 14:58:45",
        "hu": "545",
        "id": "63824"
    },
    {
        "ciu": "ciudad3",
        "fe": "2018-01-02 15:35:46",
        "hu": "33",
        "id": "63853"
    }
]
```

Describiré como proceder:

- 1º Te traes el json a através de una llamada AJAX
- 2º Conviertes el JSON en un objeto usando JSON.parse
- 3º Recorres el objeto capturando los valores que quieras y metiendolos en los arrays que quieras

**Paso 1: Traerte el JSON** (El paso 2 está explicado en los comentarios del código)
Supongo que el JSON te lo traes después de hacer una llamada AJAX:

```
function getCitiesData(){
 req=new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange=function(){ 
  if (req.readyState === 4 && req.status === 200){ // readyState === 4 significa que está completo y el status === 200 significa que está OK
  jsonparsed = JSON.parse(req.responseText); //Paso 2: Conviertes el JSON en un objeto através de JSON.parse. No te olvides de declarar previamente la variable jsonparsed. 
  } else if (req.readyState === 4 && req.status === 404){
    console.log(req.responseText); //Para ver el error en el caso de que no haya podido traerse el JSON
  }

};
req.open("GET",'url-a-la-que-haces-tu-llamada-ajax',true);
req.send();
}
```

**PASO 3 Recorres el objeto** (`jsonparsed`)

Opción A

```
  jsonparsed.forEach(function(objeto){
  arrayCiudades.push(objeto.ciu);
  arrayFe.push(objeto.fe);
  arrayHu.push(objeto.hu);
  arrayId.push(objeto.id);
     }
  }); 
 }
```

Opción B (Creo que esta encaja mejor con la que me comentas)

```
  var arrayDeArrays = [];
  var fila = 0
  jsonparsed.forEach(function(objeto){
  arrayDeArrays[fila] = [];
  arrayDeArrays[fila].push(objeto.ciu);
  arrayDeArrays[fila].push(objeto.fe);
  arrayDeArrays[fila].push(objeto.hu);
  arrayDeArrays[fila].push(objeto.id);
  fila +=1;
     }
  }); 
 }
```

Ya tienes tus datos metidos en arrays en vez de tenerlo en un array de objetos ¿Es lo que querías,no?
Después quieres:

> despues de ahi comparar si en el array de ciudad1 la fecha es entre
>   2018-01-01 a 2018-01-31 guardarla en un array, esto es para checar en
>   la ciudad1 en el mes de enero cuantos registros se llenaron y asi
>   hasta llegar a diciembre, asi sucesivamente para las demas ciudades

Bueno, te diré que arrayDeArrays (Opción B) es como una pila de arrays
arrayDeArrays[0][0] te da el nombre de la ciudad del primer array de la pila.
arrayDeArrays[0][1] te da la fecha de la la ciudad del primer array de la pila.
arrayDeArrays[0][2] te da el "hu" de la ciudad del primer array de la pila.
arrayDeArrays[0][3] te da el id de la ciudad del primer array de la pila.

La verdad es que no tengo más tiempo por hoy para dedicarle a esto, lo siento..